# G360 Execute 360 Folder Open Delay

Tags: vb6, execute360, g360

I am using G360 Execute 360 CalClient vb6 API to integrate to Execute 360.

My API version is 9.1.

When opening folders type workitems from the workflow server using CalWorkitem.Open it takes very long to return the workitem folders.

THe same occurs in the WorkDesk application.

What is the cause and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the folder takes so long to open is because you are using Version 9.1.

With the 9.1 release you can have document types within document type. Emulating folders.

Install CalClient V6 and the folders will open instantly.

Also see [Global 360 Support](http://support.global360.com/)